# How does one get System Load Indicator (or something similar) working in 17.10?

Tags: system, 17.10, monitoring

After upgrading to 17.10, my System Load Indicator (*indicator-multiload*) applet turned into a tiny little box where it's no longer possible to see the different live graphs.

As per [How To Use Indicator Applets on GNOME Shell](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/use-indicator-applets-gnome-shell), I tried enabling [KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) via the switch on that page, but then the widget turns into **ERROR**, and nothing else happens.

Is there a Gnome version of this application we should be using instead?  If not, would it be possible to get [System Load Indicator](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload) working again somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug, and it's been already reported to developers of the app:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-multiload/+bug/1714804

You can upvote it if you wish, to let the developers know that it does matter for you -- maybe it'll somehow speed them up in releasing the fix?

1. Report that it affects you -- this will add 4 points of "bug heat" ("hotness").
2. Subscribe to bug's notifications -- it'll add 2 points.

(It currently has 48 points.)

But in comments in the very bug I found that there is already a not bad extension for gnome with the same features:

https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet

So there's probably no need at all to fix this bug, if one can simply use existing extension?

Its installation is a little bit tricky, but there are instructions there, I simply followed them and right now I've managed to successfully install it.

Try it yourself!

Comment: Installing it via apt didn't work, but flipping the switch on the extention page certainly did.  Thanks!

Comment: on 18.04, gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor I found with synaptic, and only had to run this on commandline to enable it: `gnome-shell-extension-tool --enable-extension=system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com` (I actually installed gir1.2... before doing it tho), it appeared on the systray, I still dont get the webbrowser part but w/e :)

Answer (score 8):

Installing Gnome extensions support and the system-monitor extension - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/ - was the solution for me.

In case you also, like me, were not familiar with the gnome extensions, please follow these steps:

1. Install add-on for your web browser:

For Google Chrome, Chromium, and Vivaldi, install the [add-on via chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep). That's what I have done, but there are also add-on for other browsers: For Firefox, install add-on from [Mozilla Addons site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/).
For Opera, install it from [Opera Addons site](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/gnome-shell-integration/).

2. Open terminal either via Ctrl+Alt+T, or by searching “terminal” from app launcher. When it opens, run the command to make it work in Chrome:

   `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell`
3. The system-monitor extension has some requirements - run the following command on the terminal:

   `sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0  gir1.2-clutter-1.0`
4. Finally go to extensions.gnome.org via your browser (I have used Chrome), install any Gnome Shell Extension by turning on the switch on the web. For the system-monitor extension, the link is https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 I also had this problem and I was missing the indicator-multiload features. I now like this system-monitor extension even more - it looks better, has relevant information, it is easier to configure and it is easy to find and install, at least when you get into the gnome extensions.

Comment: but will it be placed on the system tray or I will have to open a web browser? the systray is the right location for such kind of things (fast monitoring).

Comment: It will be placed on the system tray. The Gnome extensions add-on provides only an easy way to install it. Just have a look at the link from the extension.